# How to get Label from IValidatable in Wicket 7

Tags: wicket, wicketstuff, wicket-7

Is it possible to get the label of my component inside a validation? I need this label for a custom error message in my validation. It looks like:

*"The value may not be less than {0}."*

If my component has a label then i want to write it before like:

*"LabelName: The value may no be less than {0}."*

My component **BigDecimalValidator** doesn't know the **BigDecimalTextfield**.

```
tfiGV = new BigDecimalTextField("tfiGV", new Model<BigDecimal>());
tfiGV.setLabel(Model.of(Const_Labels.GV));
tfiGV.add(BigDecimalValidator.minimum(0));
```

The validatable of **BigDecimalValidator** can't reach the necessary label.

```
@Override
public void validate(IValidatable<BigDecimal> validatable) {
    // Doesn't work ((FormComponent<BigDecimal>) validatable).getLabel();

    if (((BigDecimal) validatable.getValue()).compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(minimum, 3)) == -1) {
            ValidationError valError = new ValidationError();
            valError.setMessage(getErrorMessageMin(minimum));
            validatable.error(valError);
    }
}
```

I know that the label can be reached by a constructor for **BigDecimalValidator** but this isn't a nice solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `{label}` in your i18n message and Wicket will replace it with the form component's label.

E.g. `{label}: The value may not be less than {0}.`

Comment: Could You remind me, this feature depends on specific creation of pair XxxxxTextField / Label ?